# In a batch file, how do I separate a file name and a file extention from a file path?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that accepts a file path. I then need to isolate the file name and the file extention separately. For example, if my file path is "\svr-01\My Docs\My Spreadsheet.xls" then I need two separate variables; one containing 'My SpreadSheet" and one containing ".xls".

Heres what i have so far. I have been able to seperate the filename and extention from the path:

```
set FILEPATH=\\SVR-01\My Docs\My Spreadsheet.xls
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%FILEPATH%") do set "FILENAME=%%~nxA"
echo.%FILENAME%
```

How do i then separate the file name and the extention from this variable?

Answer (score 5):

```
set FILEPATH=\\SVR-01\My Docs\My Spreadsheet.xls
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%FILEPATH%") do (
  set "FILEFULLNAME=%%~nxA"
  set "FILENAME=%%~nA"
  set "FILEEXT=%%~xA"
)
set file
```

Comment: Out of interest, what does the last line do?

Comment: @BaliC - It just prints out all the definitions of variables that begin with `file`, case insensitive. I put it there just to show the results of the assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%~n` for filename and `%~x` for the extension.

What you have already just combines the two. Use them separately for each part.

```
rem Filename
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%FILEPATH%") do set "FILENAME=%%~nA"

rem Extension
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%FILEPATH%") do set "FILENAME=%%~xA"
```

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ben/archive/2007/03/09/path-manipulation-in-a-batch-file.aspx) for more options.

Comment: Sounds simple enough, do i need two more for loops then?

Comment: dbenham has done it in one loop, using a code block for setting multiple variables

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at

%~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
%~d1        - expands %1 to a drive letter only
%~p1        - expands %1 to a path only
%~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
%~x1        - expands %1 to a file extension only
%~s1        - expanded path contains short names only
%~a1        - expands %1 to file attributes
%~t1        - expands %1 to date/time of file
%~z1        - expands %1 to size of file

especialy

> %~p1        - expands %1 to a path only